# Map irregular quadrangle to square

Tags: geometry

Say I map an arbitrary quadrangle ABCD to a square A'B'C'D', A will be mapped to A'(0,0), B mapped to B'(1,0), C mapped to C'(1,1), D mapped to D'(0,1), P mapped to P'(u,v). How do I get P'(u,v) in the square given the coordinates of A B C D P ?

[image]

Comment: Assume the quadrilateral is convex, the reverse direction (from square to quadrilateral) is easy, just apply a [bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation). For the direction from quadrilateral to square, you can try to invert the bilinear interpolation. see this stackoverflow.SE [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808441/inverse-bilinear-interpolation) for ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how well this will work, but you could use the following simultaneous equations, which are a kind of bilinear interpolation:

$$P_x = (1-u)(1-v) A_x + u(1-v) B_x + uv C_x + (1-u)v D_x\\
P_y = (1-u)(1-v) A_y + u(1-v) B_y + uv C_y + (1-u)v D_y$$

Comment: Thanks, it works. Takes a little time to solve the equations.

Comment: @JGrey, did you work out a parametrized solution where you can plug in P, A, B, C and D to get u and v out?

I'm trying to do this by hand now, but my brain is starting to hurt >.< I'm just a simple programmer =(